# jquery autocomplete get data from local file

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete

I am trying to get data for autocomplete, however when I yield no results. No errors, no nothing.

```
$(document).ready(function()
        {
            $('#txtAutoComplete').autocomplete({
            delay: 0,
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "auto.json",
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: request,
                    success: function( data ) {
                        response( $.map( data, function( item ) {
                            return(item.name)
                        }));
                    }
                }); 
               },  
               minLength: 1
              });   
        });
```

The example json file is :

```
[
    {
        "name": "John",
        "value": "Doe"
    }{
        "name": "1",
        "value": "2"
    }{
        "name": "33",
        "value": "44"
    }{
        "name": "name",
        "value": "surname"
    }
]
```

I have placed the auto.json file to the same folder as the javascript file. However I will need to use different folders in the future. I have one question at this point : would it work if I set url as "/homeDirectoryPath/auto.json" ? or how can I use a file in another folder within the same project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your JSON file is not valid JSON.    Try this:

```
[
    {
        "name": "John",
        "value": "Doe"
    },{
        "name": "1",
        "value": "2"
    },{
        "name": "33",
        "value": "44"
    },{
        "name": "name",
        "value": "surname"
    }
]
```

Use JSONLint if you want to validate your JSON data.

http://jsonlint.com/

The following worked for me with the above JSON data.  I do not have the script you are using, so I just was testing the ajax function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "auto.json",
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function( data ) {

                                console.log(data);
                        }
                });
});
```

Comment: You should post a working example to jsfiddle.  I was able to strip out some things at get it to work with the following code:

$(document).ready(function() {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "auto.json",
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function( data ) {

                                console.log(data);
                        }
                });
});